# Whats the usecase of "write protected" PAT memory type?

Tags: memory, x86, cpu-cache, osdev, page-tables

[image]

What's the use case of "write protected" memory type?

Comment: Looks like an alternate form of write-through, where stores force eviction like NT stores, instead of updating the cache.  IDK if it's useful for anything; WT is very rarely used either, although I have seen a paper that benchmarked WT against normal WB  for a workload like SPECint, IIRC.  I forget what the point of the paper was.

Comment: Maybe for those devices that share the same MMIO location for a write-only and a read-only register? For example, imagine location X in memory when read gets the last device error code and when written execute a command. In this case, you may want to cache the last error but invalidate it every time a command is written. And of course, you want the command to go all the way to "memory". But it seems a very specific case that doesn't justify the effort.